# Connecting to all available Wifi networks on Android

Tags: java, android, networking, wifi, wifimanager

I am trying to make an app that, once connected, runs a specific method on each available network that have been used in the past. I try to make sure that the wifi is fully connected before running the method and connecting to the next available network, but that part of code seems to not be working correctly.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
        List<WifiConfiguration> networkList  = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
    List<ScanResult> scannedList  = wifiManager.getScanResults();
    for (ScanResult i: scannedList){
        for (WifiConfiguration z: networkList){
            if(z.SSID.substring(1, (z.SSID.length() - 1)).equals(i.SSID)){  
                //System.out.println("NETWORK: " + i.SSID);
                System.out.println("NETWORK: " + i.SSID + "STATE " + wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSupplicantState().toString());
                wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(z.networkId, true);
                wifiManager.reconnect();
                while(wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getSupplicantState().toString() != "COMPLETED"){
                }
                runMethod(wifiManager);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a broadcast receiver so that you can put your code in it's onReceive ?

Comment: @Shereef Hmmm... I will look into that. How exactly will that help? (I am not too familiar with Broadcasters + Receivers)?

Comment: Instead of looping until it's connected you 2 onReceive will run when connected or disconnected